# Messing with ternary operator

Tags: conditional-operator

I want to convert the if statements in the function into ternary operator. This function is to select any element.

```
function s(el, index, all){
    if(el !== undefined && index === undefined)
        return document.querySelector(el);
    else if(el !== undefined && index !== undefined && all === true)
        return document.querySelectorAll(el);
    else
        return document.querySelectorAll(el)[index];
}
```

Comment: Please add a language tag. (JavaScript?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JS Ternary functions with multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022445/js-ternary-functions-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0):

```
return (el !== undefined && index === undefined)?document.querySelector(el):(el !== undefined && index !== undefined && all === true)?document.querySelectorAll(el):document.querySelectorAll(el)[index];
```

Comment: condition A ? value A :Condition B ? value B : condition C ? value C :....
If conditon A is true, value A is selected, else Condition B is checked. If condition B is  true value B is selected, else COndition C  is checked, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a clean way like this

```
function s(el, index, all){
    let firstCondition = el !== undefined && index === undefined;
    let secondCondition = el !== undefined && index !== undefined && all === true;
    return firstCondition ? document.querySelector(el) : secondCondition ? document.querySelectorAll(el) : document.querySelectorAll(el)[index];
}
```