# Skip If statement below if first part is true

Tags: reactjs

I am trying I have code here which works great

```js
{Money.toString().endsWith('54') ? (
  <div className="tg">Take 5% off< /div>
  ) : (
  <div className="tg">Take 15% off</div>
  )}
```

Which is awesome but now i need to add an if statement before it to skip that statement if its true

```js
{ID.toString().startsWith('BGM') === true (
 ''
} ? 
{Money.toString().endsWith('97') ? (
<div className="tg">Take 5% </div>
) : (
<div className="tg">Take 15%</div>
              )}
```

Skip the discount.

Is a switch statement the best way to handle this?

This is being rendered in the return statement now

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022445/js-ternary-functions-with-multiple-conditions. The decision to use a switch or ternary is subjective, but generally use switch statements when ternaries get too messy

Answer (score 0):

Got it

```js
              {ID.toString().startsWith('lbz') === true ? (
                <><div className="tg">Take 105% off</div></>
              ) : (Price.toString().endsWith('97') ? (
                <><div className="tg">Take 5% off</div></>
              ): (
                <div className="tg">Take 15% off</div>
              ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
{!ID.toString().startsWith('BGM') && 
  Money.toString().endsWith('97') ? (
  <div className="tg">Take 5% </div>
) : (
  <div className="tg">Take 15%</div>
)}
```

With this, if the `ID.toString().startsWith('BGM')` returns true, the ! operator will set value as false and the `Money.toString().endsWith('97')` condition wont be evaluated and you wont return anything