# React nested conditional rendering in return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, return

I have the following code

```
return (
  
  <Container>
    
    {param1==false && param2==false &&(
      <CustomComponent> 
      </CustomComponent>
      )}
      
    {param1 == false && param2==true &&( 
      <CustomComponent2> 
      </CustomComponent2>
      )}
      
    <Container>  
    </Container>

  </Container>
);
```

The problem right now is the `<Container>` component is still being rendered after the custom component checks have been made, which makes sense.

I want it so only 1 component is rendered ( either custom, custom2 or just the container ) from the docs here - https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering#conditionally-returning-jsx I know you can use ternary operator to conditionally render components but I have 3 cases to check not 2.

Now I could do nested ternary operators but that is not readable so I would like to know an alternative !

Comment: Nobody but you knows the details of the conditions that determine what should be rendered.

Comment: have a seperate function which returns the approriate component based on if else if else?

Comment: In general though how would one go about handling rendering when there are 3 cases though, assuming conditions are as simple as possible

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022445/js-ternary-functions-with-multiple-conditions) helps

Comment: @cmgchess I think it might be best to pull the first two component checks into a function, then do a single ternary operator check between that functions return and the container below !

Comment: @OnePiece so many ways to do such that you are free to implement what suits best for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    you can check a multiple conditions in ternary operator
     like this
    
    return (
<>
     <Container>
        {param1==false && param2==false ?
          <CustomComponent> 
          </CustomComponent> :
           param1 == false && param2==true ? 
           <CustomComponent2>     
           </CustomComponent2> :
        <Container>  
        </Container>
       }  
 </Container>
</>
);
```